# Objective-C multiple pointers to same object?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, sprite-kit

Ive searched around and can't find any answers that aren't related to C++, which isn't the exact same thing. I have a game and I keep an `NSMutableArray` of my sprites for certain categories because there are too many of them and they appear/dissapear too often to keep references to every single one of them, and also the number of them varies. so they are stored in an array.

In my `didBeginContact` method I grab the `contact.bodyA.node` object and pass it into a mehtod I've written called `getSprite` which enumerates over the array of objects I have, finds the one that matches and returns that one as an `SKSpriteNode` so I can use `SKSpriteNode`-specific methods such as `animateWithFrames` and such. However, I use this method pretty frequently and I'm wondering if doing something like:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = (SKSpriteNode*)[contact.bodyB.node parent];
```

Is acceptable as well, and then just using that pointer to refer to my object. It works, but I don't know if it will cause memory leaks or other problems. Any suggestions? (the reason I used the parent method is because the sprite I'm actually after is the parent of the one involved in the collision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using ARC.  The local pointer to the object is a strong pointer by default, since you didn't specify anything differently.  So that object is guaranteed to not be destroyed during the scope in which your local `sprite` pointer exists.  It will not maintain a strong reference beyond that scope.  The `NSMutableArray` also maintains a strong reference to to the objects it contains, so while they are in that array, the objects will not be destroyed.

Comment: Yep, this. That local reference is a great thing because it improves readability, and C++ and C (and therefore Obj-C) have been handling that case for decades, so there are likely no worries.

Answer (score 0):

As far as memory leaks go, this shouldn't cause any problems.  It should also be more performant since it's a direct link back up to the sprite, rather than iterating and searching for the correct sprite.   I don't see any reason why you couldn't do that, besides the fact that is might affect future plans for your game since the parent relationship of the object becomes part of the logic when is probably shouldn't be, but if you centralize that code so it's easy to change if you ever change the hierarchy of your sprites it should be fine.